# How do I get SwitchTranition to work with CSSTransition with TypeScript

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-transition-group

So I have been using `react-trasition-group` to perform transition on different states of the same element and all is working fine there. The problem arises when there are multiple(two) elements to transition between. I am not sure how it works in the [documentation](https://reactcommunity.org/react-transition-group/switch-transition) but whenever I enter the `key` TypeScript goes crazy ans tells me that `key` cannot be boolean, which is completely understandable as `key` is something reserved by React to be used as a unique identifier for dynamically generated elements.

**My attempt**

```
const [trigger, setTrigger] = useState(false)

return(
  <SwitchTransition mode="out-in">
    <CSSTransition
      addEndListener={(node: HTMLElement, done: () => void) => {
        node.addEventListener("transitionend", done, false)
      }}
      classNames="myclass"
      key={trigger}
    >
      {trigger ? (
        <p>Render when true</p>
      ) : (
        <p>Render when false</p>
      )}
    </CSSTransition>
  </SwitchTransition>
)
```

The error that I am getting is due to the above written fact and I cannot find in the documantation how the `SwitchTransition` is supposed to work. Any help is appreciated.|

PS: I have checked the for similar issues on Github and Stackoverflow but apparently no one has com across this similar error before.

**Edit:** I guess I should have elaborated further since I have had 2 suggestions asking me to change the boolean to string. That is not my issue. My issue is that the transition itself is not working which arises due to the fact the `react-transition-group` for some reason wants a key as written in the documentation. I also noticed that `addEndListener` is causing issues as well.

Comment: So change it to string instead of boolean.

Comment: The key doesn't have to be a boolean - it can be a string, or a number. I was also recently wondering on how it works and I put a small [POC](https://codesandbox.io/p/sandbox/react-transition-group-modal-chk2lx)

Answer (score 4):

Yes, indeed the Typescript version has some differences. Here's a working version.

```
const [trigger, setTrigger] = useState(0);
const nodeRef = useRef<any>(null);
return(
  <div>
    <button onClick={() => setTrigger(trigger + 1)}>toggle</button>
    <SwitchTransition mode="out-in">
      <CSSTransition
        nodeRef={nodeRef}
        addEndListener={(done: () => void) => {
          nodeRef.current?.addEventListener("transitionend", done, false);
        }}
        classNames="myclass"
        key={trigger}
      >
        <div ref={nodeRef}>
            <p>{trigger}</p>
        </div>
      </CSSTransition>
    </SwitchTransition>
  </div>
)
```

The `nodeRef` is used to provide a element reference to the transitions component, preventing this error:

`Warning: findDOMNode is deprecated in StrictMode. findDOMNode was passed an instance of Transition which is inside StrictMode. Instead, add a ref directly to the element you want to reference.`

See demo at: https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ts-fcyubb?file=index.tsx

Comment: Amazing! Thank you for posting.  This was super helpful.